# Pass query value to new URL - regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to set up some server redirects.

I have an old URL: `/product-category/pillows/?pa_position=back-sleeper`

The new URL is: `/product-category/pillows/?_position=back-sleeper`

The `?_position` parameter is new, however the values remain the same. Is there an appropriate regex expression to pass the original param value to the new URL?

Comment: Just replace `?pa_position` with `?_position`. The rest of the URL will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar suggested you could simply replace `pa_position` with `_position`. Following sed command would do the job.

```
sed 's/pa_position/_position/'
```

If you want to capture the last part of the URL you can use the following regex:

```
\/product-category\/pillows\/\?pa_position=\(.*\)
```

The string 'back-sleeper' in this case will then be accessible as the first matched group (\1) of this regex.